# Django view not rendering - sidebar & header loads fine but main content does not load

Tags: django

I've been through so many different things and I just can't work it out; need a fresh set of eyes haha

My view does not render and this seems to be the case across my apps and landing page - the sidebar and header loads fine, footer looks to partially load but I believe this is due to the fact the main content does not load.

[Current HTML page screenshot - not rendering view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkXqM.png)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

# Form Imports
from .models import NewRecipeForm

#########################################  
# Form Pages                            #
#########################################

# Recipe View
class RecipesView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        content = {}
        content['heading'] = "Recipes Database"
        content['pageview'] = "Recipes & Formulations"
        return render(request, 'nf_recipes/recipes-database.html', content)

#########################################  
# Form Pages                            #
#########################################

# Add New Recipe Form
class AddNewRecipeForm(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        add_new_recipe_form = NewRecipeForm()
        content = {}
        content['heading'] = "Add New Recipe"
        content['pageview'] = "Recipes & Formulations"
        content['add_new_recipe_form'] = add_new_recipe_form
        return render(request, 'nf_recipes/add-new-recipe.html', content)
    
    def post(self, request):
        if "add-new-recipe-submit" in request.POST:
            add_new_recipe_form = NewRecipeForm(request.POST)
            add_new_recipe_form.save()
            return redirect("/nf_recipes/recipe-db")
# End of Add New Recipe Form
```

**add-new-recipe.html**

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block contents %}
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="class-body">
                <!-- Add New Recipe Form -->
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row-fluid pb-1">
                            <!-- Recipe Name -->
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <!-- Test page content -->
                                <h3>This is a test</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End of Add New Recipe Form -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_javascript %}
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, Textarea, DateInput
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#########################################  
# Static Datasets                       #
#########################################

# Unit Measurement Sets
unit_measure = [
    (0,'g'),
    (1,'kg'),
    (2,'cup'),
    (3,'cups'),
    (4,'tsp'),
    (5,'tbsp'),
    (6,'cl'),
    (7,'ml'),
    (8,'l')
]

#########################################  
# Models                                #
#########################################

# New Recipe Model
class Recipes(models.Model):
    recipe_idpk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Recipe Name")
    recipe_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Recipe Addition Date")
    recipe_description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Recipe Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.recipe_name}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-recipe_date']
        verbose_name = 'Recipes'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Recipes'

#########################################  
# Forms                                 #
#########################################

# New Recipe Form
class NewRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = ["recipe_name","recipe_description"]
```

Comment: Does your base.html define `{% block content %}` or `{% block contents %}`?

Comment: @evergreen was the first thing on my radar and the base.html indeed has the required ```{% block contents %}``` - it is driving me crazy haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in my base.html file - it appeared that my divider for layout-wrapper was not closed with `</div>`.

Anyone with similar issues, review your primary templates for your HTML and check to see if all dividers have been closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you're using the `get()` method to add the `context` to your views in your case `content`.

change your view to use `get_context_data()` [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context-1).

example **views.py**

```
# Recipe View
class RecipesView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'nf_recipes/recipes-database.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecipesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context.update({
            'heading': "Recipes Database",
            'pageview': "Recipes & Formulations"
        })

        return context
```

You might also want to check that your `base.html` file has the `{% block contents%}` tag in it

Comment: As per above, base.html has the required ```{% block contents %}``` tags. Thank you for your suggestion, I tried this but unfortunately, I'm still seeing a blank render :(

Comment: I see you're importing `from django.views import View` and adding that as a parameter in `RecipesView(...)`. use `TemplateView` instead. I have corrected the answer above @OzKan

Comment: Thanks - amended to TemplateView but again nothing - still renders blank. It is so frustrating lol

Comment: Could you please add the `base.html` file in the question for reference.

Comment: The issue was in the base.html file, there was no </div> after the layout-wrapper divider. :)